# Async function results undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am still new to async functions so I'm still learning. I am trying to use an async function to find the closest station based on specific coordinates. I used the Google Geocoder to find the longitude and latitude of a location from the user and made an API request to Worldtides with the coordinates to find the station. However, when I try to get the closest station's coordinates, longlatResults comes back undefined. Also, longlatResults only comes back undefended the first time. Once I run it again, it works fine. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is the code that throws an error where longlatResults is undefined.

```
    var geo = geocoder({
            key: "******************"
    })
    geo.find(req.body.location, function (err, result) {
        const lat = result[0].location.lat;
        const lng = result[0].location.lng;
        const findLongLat = "https://www.worldtides.info/api/v3?stations&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&stationDistance=50&key=************"

        async function getJSON(url) {
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            return Promise.resolve(response.data.stations);
        }
    
        const data = getJSON(findLongLat).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
        })

        data.then(async (longlatResults) => {
            const newLat = longlatResults[0].lat;
            const newLong = longlatResults[0].lon;
        })
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `lat` and `lon` you are using but when I go to `https://www.worldtides.info/api/v3?stations&lat=1&lon=1&stationDistance=50&key=95799540-4db3-459b-b230-b8ea763b84f4` the response contains an array of 0 stations so it would make sense that `response.data.stations[0]` would be `undefined`.

Comment: Did they just leak their API key?

Comment: a) don't mix `async/await` and `.then()` and/or `.catch()`. Pick a system and stick with it. b) `newLat` and `newLong` have to be used within the `then(function () {` context.

Comment: @caTS I did "leak" my API key because I know that I can just change them whenever I want to. Thanks for letting me know though.

Comment: @RockySims When I put actually coordinates into the URL, I still get an array of stations as a response. I do get an error from axios saying getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.worldtides.info, but when I click the link it provides it still gives me an array of stations.

Comment: What is the exact `url` you are passing to `axios.get()`?

Comment: Well if axios throws an error, how would you expect it to return any result. Check the url you are passing to axios and set a breakpoint inside `getJSON` to see what it actually returns ...

Answer (score 0):

Async functions always return a promise implicitly.

You don't need to explicitly return a promise in `getJSON()`, because the async keyword will convert whatever you return into a promise automatically.

I'm fairly certain your code is returning a promise that returns a promise which returns the data right now, which is why you can't access any properties of the data outside the method.

You should be able to change the line to this:

```js
return response.data.stations;
```

Comment: I changed the line, but longlatResults is still coming back undefined the first time. I get an error from axios with the data being undefined, however, when I click the URL it gives me, I get the correct array of stations.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not working properly because you are not ,,waiting" for the response. Instead you are using the promise.

```
        const data = await getJSON(findLongLat).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
        })
```

This should work

Comment: I thought await is only valid inside async function

Comment: This is just wrong. If you look closely at OP's code (how bad the style may be of mixing `async/await` and `.then / .catch` may be) you will see that `getJSON` returns a promise which then gets a `.then` handler attached ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).